# AT+CGATT? returns "ERROR" from SIM800C module when connected with Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, gsm, gprs, sim800

I have used the SoftwareSerial library and Serial interface to communicate between SIM800C and Arduino in serial communication mode.

I gave

`AT
    AT+CSQ
    AT+CGATT?
    AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"`

etc via Serial monitor. When I used it for the first time, these commands worked fine.
But I put the sim back to my android phone to find the correct APN for 2G settings.
After I found out the APN settings, I put the sim back to SIM800C and tried the above commands.

`AT and AT+CSQ` return OK.
But

> AT+CGATT?, AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS" return ERROR.

Then I try following commands too If someone needs to help me find the answer to this question.

I'm a beginner, so I don't need exactly what these commands mean. So if you need more details to ask me.

My intention is to send data to a website.

```
 AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,0
OK
at+cgreg?
+CGREG: 0,0
OK
AT+CGATT?  
ERROR
AT+COPS=?
+COPS: (1,"Hutchison Lanka (Pvt)","Hutch","41308"),(3,"Mobitel","MOBITEL","41301"),(2,"CELLTEL INFINITI","CELLTEL","41303"),(3,"DIALOG","DIALOG","41302"),,(0-4),(0-2)
```

Comment: Retry commands sequence after providing `AT+CMEE=1` or `AT+CMEE=2`, please.

Answer (score 0):

First, You're not registreted in the network. Second, do CGATT=1 If you get error wait, because attach can take a time. Even up to 13,5min. Read 3GPP docs about registering to the network and about GPRS attach procedure.